# Jenkins all build parameters(key and value) concatenation as single string

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a jenkins-pipeline which will concatenate all build params as single string (as we need this in cURL api call as a shell argument)

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        script {
          for (entry in params) {
            echo "Build param: ${entry.key} - ${entry.value}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please help me to concatenate all params as single string ==>
`"param1=value1&param2=value&param3=value3&..."` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve `key` and `value` of the parameters you will need to use `getKey()` and `getValue()` functions. For string concatenation I used `+` operator.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        script {
          def curl = ""
          for (entry in params) {
            curl += entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + "&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Groovy Strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_strings.htm)